# Custom State Machine Workflow with navigation based on user input

Tags: 2010, workflow, custom, display-form

Here's what I have to do:
I have a list of items called **Projects**, and for this I have developed a custom display form called **DisplayProject.aspx**, and a custom *State Machine Workflow*.
I have to put a button on the **DisplayProject.aspx** page that will advance the workflow to the next state. Also, **State** is an attribute of the **Project** entity.
I am quite new to SharePoint Development and most of the examples I find online regarding State Machine Workflows are specific document approval workflows.
How can I design such a page, and how can I design such a workflow?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find an answer.

For reference, check out this links:
- http://www.sharepointology.com/setup/add-web-parts-to-dispform-editform-or-newformaspx/
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/StateMachineWorkflows.aspx

If any of you is interested in presenting the full solution, tell me so.